# How to run same keyword over multiple variables in Robot Framework

Tags: for-loop, robotframework, keyword

I have the following example:

```
Keyword A
[Arguments]  ${variablesA}  ${variablesB}
     Mouse Over  ${variablesA}
     Mouse Over  ${variablesB}
Keyword B
[Arguments]  ${variablesA}  ${variablesB}  ${variablesC}
     Mouse Over  ${variablesA}
     Mouse Over  ${variablesB}
     Mouse Over  ${variablesC}
```

Looking at above example, I just want to create a single Keyword that can handle any number of variables to be run against `Mouse Over`.

I see that we can use `FOR` in combination with `Create List` but I think in that approach we are required to determine the number of items from the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use variable number of arguments:

```
Keyword C
    [Arguments]    @{arguments}
    :FOR    ${argument}    IN    @{arguments}
    \    Mouse Over    ${argument}
```